# Running application with java + maven + tomcat (embedded) the port is not found

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, tomcat

I've got no previous experience with java. Trying to run project from github - https://github.com/ESPD/ESPD-Service. The Service uses Maven for building multi-module Maven project. I'm using `mvn clean package` in order to generate the `project.war` file. Then type `java -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -Xms768m -Xmx768m -jar project.war` and the app is running in a Tomcat container with port 8080 and it shows on the cmd console that the app is running perfectly but the problem comes when i try to access the localhost:8080. It says Not Found and I've been looking all over the internet to find a solution but without success. Will appreciate a lot if someone gives me a hand on that one.

Comment: By `Not Found` do you mean 404 error?

Comment: Yes exactly - HTTP ERROR 404

Comment: It means your browser has found the server, but you are not on any recognizable `endpoint`.

Comment: I have all of the endpoints on my console but none of them are responding ....

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: @S.Minchev please create an answer describing how you fixed your problem, and accept it as the correct answer 24 hours afterwards. This benefits any future visitor who has the same problem as you and finds this question.

Comment: The `/ESPD-Service/espd-web/pom.xml` file contains a snippet marking the servlet container (Tomcat, in this case) as being provided. However, it is located under the **non-embedded** profile which seems to be the mistake. I'd recommend to change the line `<id>non-embedded</id>` to `<id>embedded</id>` as the **embedded** profile is the one declared as active in the main pom file `/ESPD-Service/pom.xml`.

Comment: @S.Minchev hi, can you please provide an answer. I need to implement the same project, and also don't have any java expirience. Also which maven version and which java jdk version are you using. Thanks for any info.

Comment: @SehaxX hi, i have already described it in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Java version should be JDK 1.8,
Maven version must be no greater than 3.5.0

Then add 2 libraries to ESPD-Service\espd-web\target\espd-web\WEB-INF\lib folder: mail-1.4.7.jar and activation-1.1.1.jar cuz they are currently missing.

After that run `mvn install` in order to install all the jars files and then run the `java -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -Xms768m -Xmx768m -jar espd-web.war` as it's written on the docs. And also when the app is running on `localhost:8080` make sure you add `localhost:8080/espd`